# sorting array with functions without using pointers in C didn't work out. why?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I was trying to sort an array with sending my array to a function but it gives error when compiling. My sorting algorithm might be wrong but that is not a point. I wonder why my compilers give error. Here is my errors :

error: conflicting types for ‘sortarray’
 void sortarray(int d[],int size)

note: previous declaration of ‘sortarray’ was here
 void sortarray(int,int);

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 9
void sortarray(int,int);

int main()
{
    int i;
    int c[SIZE]= {2,6,8,10,12,89,68,45,37};
    printf("sorting array program: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",c[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    sortarray(c,SIZE);

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",c[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void sortarray(int d[],int size){

int hold;
int i,j;

for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < size-1; j++)
    {
        d[j+1]=hold;
        d[j+1]=d[j];
        d[j]=hold;
    }
}
return;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Think about the statement `d[j+1]=hold;` a little extra.

Comment: Also for the compiler, when declared in an argument `int d[]` is actually exactly equal to `int *d`. And note that plain `c` in the `main` function decays to a pointer to its first element, i.e. `&c[0]`. Lastly, the message you get is really very clear.

Comment: An array of ints is not the same as an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear.

You declared your function as:

```
void sortarray(int,int);
```

But define it as

```
void sortarray(int d[],int size)
```

These are not the same, as the type of the first argument are different.

Change the declaration to match the definition:

```
void sortarray(int [],int);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `void sortarray(int,int);` to `void sortarray(int *,int);`, the first parameter is an array.